# Why batchWrite only write up to 3 data? Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore to store data for my Reactjs app. I have a function as such:

```js
export async function batchAddProduct(data) {
  const productRef = doc(collection(db, "product"));
  const batch = writeBatch(db);

  for (const datum of data) {
    batch.set(productRef, datum);
  }

  return await batch
    .commit()
    .then(() => {
      return { data: true, error: null };
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return { data: null, error: err };
    });
}
```

So basically, I want to add lots of data at once. Hence, I'm using the `writeBatch` method. I see from an answer in SO where they use `doc(collection(db, "product")` to generate an empty doc first then use `batch.set()` to fill the doc. So I'm doing that here, and I'm passing up to 500 data at once (which is the maximum limit of a batch write), but somehow only up to 3 data is being written into the database. Why is that? Am I missing something?

## Update:

According to the comment:

1. When I `console.log(data)`, it basically prints out an array with 500 objects in it (which I definitely can't paste in here). But I can assure you that it is receiving the correct data.
2. `batchAddProduct` is called in a redux sagas as such:

```js
function* BATCH_ADD_PRODUCT(input) {
  yield put({
    type: actions.SET_STATE,
    payload: {
      loadingUpdate: true,
    },
  });

  const { data, error } = yield call(batchAddProduct, input.payload.data);
  if (data) {
    yield put({
      type: actions.GET_PRODUK,
    });

    yield put({
      type: actions.SET_STATE,
      payload: {
        loadingUpdate: false,
        alert: {
          type: "success",
          message: "Product is added successfully.",
        },
      },
    });
  }

  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    yield put({
      type: actions.SET_STATE,
      payload: {
        loadingUpdate: false,
        alert: {
          type: "error",
          message: error.message || "Error occured.",
        },
      },
    });
  }
}
```

and I use this in a `dispatch` as such:

```js
dispatch({
    type: actions.BATCH_ADD_PRODUK,
    payload: {
        data: data, // WHICH CONTAINS UP TO 500 OBJECTS
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you please run `console.log(data.length, data)` and share the output? Are you sure you are passing all the items? Also please share the code where `batchAddProduct` is called from so we can check that,

Comment: Have you tried without a generator function as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/f73eda2da1c3d863100c7e6f58a6c558) (uses old syntax but with same logic)?

Comment: How to use the old syntax? Everytime I try to use the old syntax, it just throw me an error saying something like `doc.collection` is not a function. @Dharmaraj

Comment: I meant you can use same logic with newer syntax, I added another file to same gist. Can you try that once? Just replace `update()` with your `set()` operations

Comment: @Dharmaraj Definitely not working, `data` here is an array of object, I feel like your code is wrong, I can't simply replace `update()` with `set()`

Comment: @Dharmaraj You're trying to `getDocs()` but here, I don't even have a collection called `product` for example and I want to create that if it doesn't already exists.

Comment: Why can't you use set instead of update? I just want you to try the batched write part. In that case I don't have data in an array so I had to get docs, you just need to run loop on your array instead of the querySnapshot as in my case. Try the updated 2nd gist...  I hope that is clear.

Comment: @Dharmaraj It works perfectly thank you so much. I'm still confused though why my code didn't work.

Comment: I've posted this one as an answer. I'll check on the generator function later and try to check the issue with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried the generator function with a batched write yet but try the following:

```
const myArray: any = []
const batches: WriteBatch[] = []
myArray.forEach((doc, i) => {
  if (i % 500 === 0) {
    batches.push(writeBatch(db))
  }

  const productRef = doc(collection(db, 'colName'))
  const batch = batches[batches.length - 1]
  batch.set(productRef, { ...data  })
})

await Promise.all(batches.map((batch) => batch.commit()))
console.log('done')
```